# Using struts2 redirect-action over https

Tags: https, struts2

I have a problem with struts2 and redirect-action over https.

Basically the redirect response I get back from my https request has a non-secure location (i.e. http://...).

So that means the browser goes from a secure session to a non-secure session.

Any idea what could cause this?

Cheers,

Stuart.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was not in Struts 2 although the solution posted by Umesh would also have worked.

The environment I was working in had the SSL connections terminated by a load balancer before it reached the Apache front end.  This meant the AJP request to Tomcat appeared to be HTTP and the redirect URL in the response from the Struts redirect-action was written as HTTP.

The solution I chose was to write a separate connector in tomcat's server.xml for the HTTPS connections, specifying:

```
secure="true"
scheme="https"
proxyPort="443"
```

Answer (score 3):

Struts 2 itself does not support SSL switching by default
If you are switching from HTTPS mode to HTTP and vice-versa my best bet is to use Struts2-ssl plugin.
This plugin will take care of the switching based on the method annotation or the configuration you have provides.

here are the details 
[Struts2-SSL plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-ssl-plugin/wiki/HowToUse)

Comment: I don't want to use struts to switch to HTTPS, I just want the redirect response to maintain the mode of the original request.

Comment: @user1073338:That's what i am telling you struts2 do not have any build in mechanism to handle such protocol and redirection will be done by the container not the framework itself

Comment: You are right - it was the tomcat container rewriting the redirect URL  to HTTP because the SSL connection had been terminated before it reached tomcat.

Comment: :) Since handling secure/unsecured connection is the work of container and not the framework itself

Comment: This plugin does not redirect https urls back to http when not in @Secure scope. Any fixes or work-arounds for this?