# Struts 2 Redirection HTTPS with Apache Proxy pass + Jboss not working

Tags: java, apache, redirect, struts2, jboss

i have a struts2 application  running on JBoss Application Server 5.0  which is behind the apache server. Means all my request goes via apache server to the jboss server. For this i have configured ssl and proxy pass on the apache server. Everything works good except struts2 redirection.

```
Proxy Pass /testapp http://test.domain.net:8080/testapp/
```

One of my result type in struts.xml is redirection with the following example

```xml
<result name="test1" type="redirectAction">action1</result>

<action name="action1" class="com.test.actionclass1">
<result name="success">/page1.jsp </result>
</action>
```

The redirect url is not maintaining the https protocol rather it creates http protocol because of this i am getting page cannot be displayed error page.

Expected url : https://test.domain.net/testapp/action1.action
Actual url what am i getting http://test.domain.net:8080/testapp/action1.action

I also tried to use struts2-ssl plugin on my application and configured the interceptor on struts.xml but when i try to execute i am getting looping page and now even the landing page was not loaded.

Can any one help what i am doing wrong or solution to fix this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using struts2 redirect-action over https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326040/using-struts2-redirect-action-over-https)

Comment: +1 though, still a good question. Try harder with SSL plugin