# Struts 2 'redirectAction' changes protocol from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: redirect, ssl, struts2, struts

I have a Java EE web application running in HTTP mode all the time except for authentication where we are in HTTPS.
We now need to have HTTPS all the time.

While testing, we saw a problem with Struts 2 : "redirectAction" (which generates 302 status return code on  the client side) changes the protocol from HTTPS to HTTP.

Example :

```
<struts>
    <package name="suiviaffaire" namespace="/suiviaffaire" extends="webapp">    
        <action name="*" method="{1}" class="com.myAction">

       <result name="consultRedirection" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">consult?idAffaire=${idAffaire}</param>
                <param name="parse">true</param>
                <param name="encode">true</param>
            </result>
       <result name="consult">/jsp/suiviaffaire/consult.jsp</result>
```

Network capture :

```
1) status 302 : https://localhost:8043/webapp/suiviaffaire/redirectionTypeAffaire.action?idAffaire=XXX
2) status 200 : http://localhost:8043/webapp/suiviaffaire/consult.action?idAffaire=XXX
```

We tested in WebLogic 12c and WebSphere 7 and we experienced the same issue.
Do you know if this a normal behaviour of Struts 2 or a config problem in our app?

Comment: How https is achieved/configured?

Comment: I don't know what kind of information you need. For the WebLogic server, we have an Apache HTTP Server in front.

Comment: For the WebLogic server, we have an Apache HTTP Server in front.<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:8043>
        ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
        ServerName RECETTE
        ErrorLog "logs/recette-ssl-error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/recette-ssl-access_log" common

Comment: It is probably an issue with your apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aleksandr M said, it seems an issue with the Apache server. 
When SSL is activated in the WebLogic console and hit it directly, we don't have the issue.
When hitting the apache server, we have the issue.
Seems others  had the issue too :

- https://serverfault.com/questions/181177/rewriting-302-app-server-redirect-urls-with-apache-proxy-in-the-middle
- [Using struts2 redirect-action over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326040/using-struts2-redirect-action-over-https)