# struts 2 redirection (type="redirect-Action" , type="redirect") in xml redirecting to http instead of https

Tags: struts2

We used SSL on strut-2 project. At multiple places, we used redirection in struts.xml like below in code .

```
<action name="bo_act_creditNote_Save"
            class="com.skilrock.lms.web.accMgmt.common.CreditNoteAtBoAction"
            method="doCreditNoteBo">

            <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
                    <param name="actionName">bo_act_creditNote_redirect</param>         
            </result>
        </action>

<action name="bo_act_creditNote_redirect">
            <result>
                /com/skilrock/lms/web/accMgmt/backOffice/bo_act_creditNote_Success.jsp
            </result>
        </action>
```

due to ssl browser show some error that 
http://mydomain/com/skil/lms/web/userMgmt/bo_act_creditNote_redirect.action'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

And the result page is not coming as transaction completed successfully.

To resolve this issue, we removed redirection and replace with JSP page wherever it is used.
But we want to keep redirection action.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8326040/438992

Comment: @DaveNewton already seen this link but it is not useful.